# z3 API takes too much time to solve

Tags: z3

I'm using z3 Java API for a project. For some examples, it takes too much time to solve. I've waited for hours and it still couldn't solve it. I don't know if it will ever solve. But when I print the output of Solver::toString to a file, z3 binary solves it in a second. I tried a few tactics and parameters but it didn't help.

An example is here (Theory of Lists): https://rise4fun.com/Z3/4ViO

The versions of API and binary are both 4.8.0. I'm running it on Ubuntu 18.04 64-bit.

What might be the problem here?

Comment: Just a wild guess: it could be that Z3's auto-configuration makes a different choice when run on the SMT file. You could explicitly deactivate auto-configuration to see if the runtimes/behaviour aligns if it is switched of for boths ways of running Z3.

Answer (score 0):

Impossible to tell from your description whether you're using the API incorrectly, or there's a bug in the API itself. If you can come up with a minimal example that demonstrates the issue, you might want to report it at the github z3 site so the developers can take a look. https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/issues